# Cannot execute binary file for ADOM

Tags: 16.04, bash, chmod, executable, binary

I wanted to install a roguelike on my Gallium OS system(I believe galliumos is based of off 16.04 Ubuntu) so I installed the game and ran these commands.

```
chmod +x /home/chrx/Documents/adomgraphical/adom
bash /home/chrx/Documents/adomgraphical/adom
*The file was orginally called adom, but I renamed it to adomgraphical since there is an ASCII version*
```

However, it returned this error

```
/home/chrx/Documents/adomgraphical/adom: /home/chrx/Documents/adomgraphical/adom: cannot execute binary file
```

I checked to make sure that it ran as an executable file and it does. I downloaded the 32-bit version of the game so to check that I installed the correct version of the game I ran the command:

```
uname -a
```

and got the output

```
Linux chrx 4.8.17-galliumos #1 SMP PREEMPT galliumos4 Thu Feb 23 02:27:28 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Showing that my system was 32-bit. I'm honestly not sure what the problem is. The website didn't list any packages I may have needed to install beforehand.. [Here is the download link if you want to try recreating the problem](https://www.indiedb.com/games/adom-ancient-domains-of-mystery/downloads/adom-306-release-88-ubuntu-16043-32-bit)

Thanks, Jojo

Comment: You use `bash filename` to execute  a (human readable) script file. Your file `adom` is not a script file. It may be an executable file, in which case you simply omit the `bash` in front of it.

Comment: Or, you could ask the `file` command (`file /home/chrx/Documents/adomgraphical/adom`)

Comment: When I try to use the command   `/home/chrx/Documents/adomgraphical/adom`      I got the error `/home/chrx/Documents/adomgraphical/adom: error while loading shared libraries: libnoteye.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` In the game dependencies, libnoteye.so is there however.